# React Native -- login screen loads twice after logout

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I am creating a React Native app that also features Redux. Navigation is handled by [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) and traverses a single `StackNavigator`.

Currently, I am working on the authentication flow. The initial screen is a login screen. The user can login correctly. The following screen is a navigation screen, and from the user clicks a link to where they want to go. So far so good, and we are three deep in the component tree.

However, on this last screen I have a logout link that sends the user back to the login screen, and the login screen loads twice. See this video:

[image]

The underlying problem is that in a `StackNavigator` all mounted components remain mounted, so `componentDidUpdate` constantly fires in all of them. Crucially, `componentWillUnmount` [does not fire](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1554), but each time a screen is loaded or reloaded, `constructor` and `componentDidMount` do, so managing `componentDidUpdate` becomes really difficult, as I elaborate below.

I use an `isAuthenticated` boolean saved in the Redux store to determine if the user is logged in, and I redirect to the Login component if they are not, like this:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.props.login.toJS().isAuthenticated == false) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Login'));
  };
}
```

In the third component I mention in my initial description above, the clickable link does not navigate to the `Login` component directly. Rather, it calls an action that results in `isAuthenticated` becoming false, like this:

```
logout = () => {
    this.props.logoutUser(this.props.login);
};
```

It then relies on `componentDidUpdate` to do the actual redirection.

I have tried separately using both a `currentScreen` state in the Redux store and a `shouldUpdate` local state in each separate component to manage which `componentDidUpdate` I want actually doing things. See this example of the latter below:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.state.shouldUpdate == true) {
    // Do something
  };
}
```

I have also tried a similar tactic relying on `react-navigation`'s ability to track the current screen in its state, like this:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.props.navigation.state.routeName == "SomeScreen") {
    // Do something
  };
}
```

But none of these solve the issue. I still get weird behavior with screens loading multiple times.

I also tried using the `shouldComponentUpdate` [method](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) in connection with the aforementioned `shouldUpdate` state kept locally in each component. Yet this does not lead to the intended outcome, as `shouldUpdate` ends up mysteriously changing as I traverse the navigation tree. I attribute this most likely to the `constructor` firing when a component is visited again, restoring the default local state.

How do I stop the multiple loadings of earlier screens in the `StackNavigator`? Is it in fact related to a mess of different `componentDidUpdate`'s firing in the background? If so, how should I manage this? If not, what is the likely cause?

Comment: Hey, I'd heavily suggest using a root `SwitchNavigator` instead of a `StackNavigator` instead. Because a `SwitchNavigator` only ever shows one screen at once, you can then set up a 'Signed In' and a 'Signed Out' route. This will get rid of react-navigation having to unmount several instances of the same screen. Here's an easy and fast tutorial on Medium to get you started https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/building-an-authentication-flow-with-react-navigation-fb5de2203b5c

Comment: If that would allow me to ensure only one component is mounted at a time, it would be a dream and get rid of so many headaches. I'll work through that tutorial.

Comment: I understand that feeling haha. Good luck!

Comment: Don't do navigate() in componentDidUpdate(), do it in logout()

Comment: @AndriyKlitsuk: that makes no difference, and it has the added downside of not keeping keeping navigation to/from the Login screen strictly dependent on user authentication.

Comment: @Harrison: That worked! The [boilerplate](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-boilerplate) I started with used a really old version of `react-navigation`, so at first SwitchNavigator was not working. Upgrading to the current version of that library was a nightmare, but it needed to be done at some point anyway. With the SwitchNavigator, not only is the multiple loads problem fixed, but the speed of the entire app is more than doubled! If you would like to submit your suggestion as an answer I'm more than happy to accept it.