# Login screen rendering twice after logout on React Navigation 6

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

When signing out of my app the **signin screen is getting rendered twice**. This only happens when i navigate to another screen and then go back to the initialroute. If i do not leave the initialroute after login and logout right away it only renders once as it should. But as soon as i start navigating in my app then logout the signin screen gets rendered twice.

I am using **redux** in combination with **asyncstorage** to handle the authentication flow in my app. I have only found one person with the same problem and he solved it by using SwitchNavigator instead of StackNavigator as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612421/react-native-login-screen-loads-twice-after-logout) but the SwitchNavigator has been removed in **React Navigation 6** and i cant find a solution so all help is appriciated.

**redux reducer for the user.js**

```
import {UPDATE_USER} from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
  userdata: {},
  loginStatus: -1, // -1 == loading, 0 = not logged in, 1 == logged in
};

const updateUser = (state, action) => {
  let ud = action.userdata;

  return {...state, userdata: Object.assign({}, ud), loginStatus: ud ? 1 : 0};
};

const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_USER:
      return updateUser(state, action);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default userReducer;
```

**Loading screen.js**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, useRef} from 'react';
//ThirdParty
//import CustomSplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';

//Redux
import {updateUser} from '../../redux/actions/userActions';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';

//Import STACK NAVIGATORS
import AuthNavigator from '../../navigator/AuthNavigator';
import MainNavigator from '../../navigator/MainNavigator';

function LoadingScreen() {
  const ref = useRef();
  const loginStatus = useSelector((state) => state.user.loginStatus);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('loginStatus', loginStatus);


    async function getAsyncData() {

      let data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('data');
      let dataParsed = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log("AsyncData: "+data);

      //Update redux state
      dispatch(updateUser(dataParsed)); 
    }

    getAsyncData();
  });

  if (loginStatus === -1) {
    // We haven't finished checking for the user logged in or not
    return <View style={styles.container} />;
  }

  ref && ref.current && ref.current.animateNextTransition();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Transitioning.View ref={ref} transition={TRANSITION} style={styles.transitionContainer}>
        {loginStatus === 1 && <MainNavigator />} // STACK NAVIGATOR WHEN SIGNED IN
        {loginStatus === 0 && <AuthNavigator />} // STACK NAVIGATOR WHEN SIGNED OUT
      </Transitioning.View>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default LoadingScreen;
```

**signoutFunction() inside screen**

```
const signOutAsync = async () => {
   console.log("Begin Logout");
   dispatch(updateUser(null));
   await AsyncStorage.clear();
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appeared that both navigators were mounted and affected by the login so i finally solved it by wrapping both Navigators inside a parent stack container like below.

**Loading screen.js**

```
  const RootStack = createStackNavigator();
  const RootStackScreen = () => (
    <RootStack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      {loginStatus ? (
        <RootStack.Screen name="Main" component={MainNavigator} />
      ) : (
        <RootStack.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthNavigator} />
      )}
    </RootStack.Navigator>
  );

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Transitioning.View ref={ref} transition={TRANSITION} style={styles.transitionContainer}>
        <RootStackScreen />
        {/*loginStatus === 1 && <MainNavigator />*/}
        {/*loginStatus === 0 && <AuthNavigator />*/}
      </Transitioning.View>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

Credits to: **[React native school](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQVCkqvU1uE)**